# Show backend component on admin index

Tags: module, administrator, module-display

I want to show a component in the backend index page. I have tried using the following methods in the index.php file but it doesn't show.

```
<?php                                                                                       $doc = JFactory::getDocument();
$module = JModuleHelper::getModule('mod_hello_ajax_world',$title);
//get and update params
$params = new JRegistry;
$params->loadString($module->params);
$params->set('some_param_of_module',$some_value);
//render module
$renderer = $doc->loadRenderer('module');
$content = $renderer->render($module, array('params'=> $params));
print $content;                                                                                   ?>
```

Also tried this:

```
<jdoc:include type="module" name="hello_ajax_world"/>
```

But it doesn't work either.

My module has a client type administrator.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show a module on the administrator:

Goto Extensions -> Module Manager.
Set Filter to Administrator.
Now you can see which positions you can use. For example you could add a module to the cpanel position.

But your question also holds the word component, so I'm not sure if you mean a module or component.

If you just want to show a quickicon, see [Add a quick icon in Joomla 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17664824/add-a-quick-icon-in-joomla-3)

Comment: You mean, my answer worked for you? If so, please mark it with the checkmark ;-)